# How to show hidden div onchange of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have a dropdown list where there are some inactive values.When I change a value in the dropdown I need find the id inside `divInactive` class and display the particular inactive item.User should given the message(present in `divInactive`) if he selects the inactive one.

The span values inside the `divInactive` is generated using foreach loop from model.

Spans are generated only for the inactive items.I am unable to show the inactive message.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="jaguar">Jaguar</option>
</select>

<div class="divInactive">  
  <span id="spninactive_Saab" style="display:none;">Saab is inactive</span>
  <span id="spninactive_Ferrari" style="display:none;">Ferrari is inactive</span>
  <span id="spninactive_Jaguar" style="display:none;">Jaguar is inactive</span>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drp").onchange {
    var ddlTxt = $("#drp").text();
    $(".divInactive").each(function() {

      cmpValue = $(this).find('#spninactive_' + ddlTxt).text();

      if (ddlTxt == cmpValue) {
        $(".divInactive #spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/r71nsk2t/1/)</kbd>

Comment: check this..is that what you want...https://jsfiddle.net/mogn9acz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#drp").on("change", function() {
    var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
    $(".divInactive span").hide();
    $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r71nsk2t/3/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was in your fiddle, I you have not included jquery.

I have included the jquery and edited the codes: Please check,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drp").on('change', function(e) {
        var car = $(this).val();
        var selector = ".divInactive #spninactive_"
                     + (car.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
                     + car.substr(1));

        // If there is no selector found then hide all the
        // sections.
        if (!$(selector).length) {
            $(".divInactive span").css({"display":"none"});
            return; 
        }
        $(selector).css({"display": "block"});
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/r71nsk2t/4/

Answer (score 1):

Use in this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#select").on('change', function() {
    $(".divInactive span").hide()
    var str = $(this).find('option:selected').html()
    console.log(str);

    var ele = $("#spninactive_" + str)
    if (ele) {

      ele.show();

      console.log("(present in divInactive")
    }

  })
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmMRZpkNGHaTLRJPYAX3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) which will return elements which contains the mentioned text.

Try this:

```js
  $("#drp").on('change', function() {
    var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
    $(".divInactive span").hide();
    $(".divInactive span:contains(" + ddlTxt + ")").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drp">
  <option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="jaguar">Jaguar</option>
</select>

<div class="divInactive">
  <span id="spninactive_Saab" style="display:none;">Saab is inactive</span>
  <span id="spninactive_Ferrari" style="display:none;">Ferrari is inactive</span>
  <span id="spninactive_Jaguar" style="display:none;">Jaguar is inactive</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r71nsk2t/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<select id="drp">
<option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value="honda">Honda</option>
<option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="jaguar">Jaguar</option>
</select>

<div class="divInactive">  
<span id="spninactive_Saab" style="display:none;">Saab is inactive</span>
<span id="spninactive_Ferrari" style="display:none;">Ferrari is  inactive</span>
<span id="spninactive_Jaguar" style="display:none;">Jaguar is  inactive</span>  
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#drp").on("change", function() {
    var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
    $(".divInactive span").hide();
    $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
})
});
```

check pen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPEPeM

Answer (score 0):

First of all add jquery library to your Fiddle.

You don't have to loop through the select option, jquery provides a way to solve this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#drp").on('change', function() {
         var selectValue = $("#drp option:selected").text();
         $(".divInactive span").hide();
         $('#spninactive_'+selectValue).show(); 
      }); 
   });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r71nsk2t/6/)